# "Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field" on new DRF list view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I made a new list view in my Django REST Framework app:

```
class ColumnView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Column.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ColumnSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

When I try to access it, I get the following error:

> ### FieldError at /my/new/endpoint
>
> Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are: _order, fields, from, my, model

**There's no `created` field anywhere in sight** - not in the `ColumnSerializer`, not in the `Column` Django model, nowhere. The stacktrace is really opaque, too - my app doesn't appear anywhere in it. What's going on?

Comment: It would be better if you can show your model and serializer

Comment: @MohammadFaisal, this is a self-answered question where the model and serializer happen to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable cursor pagination in your settings?

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.CursorPagination',
    ...
}
```

Be sure to read [the docs on CursorPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination) carefully:

> ### Details and limitations
>
> Proper use of cursor based pagination requires a little attention to detail. You'll need to think about what ordering you want the scheme to be applied against. The default is to order by "-created". This assumes that **there must be a 'created' timestamp field** on the model instances, and will present a "timeline" style paginated view, with the most recently added items first.

In other words, you can't have all three of these conditions:

- Using cursor pagination
- ...without specifying an ordering
- ...on a model without a `created` field

Comment: What has cursor paginatin got to do with the question?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal, please notice that this is a self-answered question. I'm documenting the fix since it's in no way obvious from the error message.