# Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have follwing structure:

```
class FullTreeAdminUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class AdminFullTreeListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FullTreeAdminUserSerializer
```

When i query `users/all` i have following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field
```

The user model looks like

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   balance = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

   objects = UserManager()
```

I cannot figure out where the problem is. I simply wanna get list of all user and i didn't expect such problems. I don't have `created` filed in my user model

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field" on new DRF list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906175/cannot-resolve-keyword-created-into-field-on-new-drf-list-view)

Comment: Yes, thank you, i use cursor pagination. But how specify ordering list query?